# 'mpirun' is not recognized as an internal ort external commands,

Tags: c++, openmp

I need to make a small openMP project. I took the example from the www.openmp.org. I can compile it with /openmp option within VC++ 2005. But, When I try to run the program, I am facing the "'mpirun' is not recognized as an internal ort external commands, operable program or batch file" error. When I search the net. I found this mpirun and mpiexec is not located XP desktop. They are only in server distribution. How can run/debug openMP programs on windows?

Or should I need to go Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention that you are using OpenMP - you shouldn't actually need to use mpirun or mpiexec, as you would with [MPICH](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpich2/) or [OpenMPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/) programs. OpenMP works in a fairly different way than message-passing libraries: OpenMP uses multiple threads within the same process, but MPICH and OpenMPI use multiple processes.

So if I understand your question correctly, you should be able to just run your executable without using mpirun or mpiexec.

If, on the other hand, you're using MPICH, the mpiexec program lives in
`{ProgramFiles}\MPICH2\bin`.

Good luck!